# Un-nest collection elements in XML from WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I have a WCF method which returns an object which contains a collection and the results look like this:

```
<getMetadataResult>
            <a:count>3</a:count>
            <a:index>0</a:index>
            <a:mediaCollection>
               <a:mediaCollection>
                  <a:albumArtURI i:nil="true"/>
                  <a:artist i:nil="true"/>
                  <a:artistId i:nil="true"/>
                  ...
```

Unfortunately what I want it to look like is this:

```
  <getMetadataResult>
    <index>0</index>
    <count>3</count>
    <total>3</total>
    <mediaCollection>
      <itemType>other</itemType>
      <id>0001</id>
    </mediaCollection>
    <mediaCollection>
      <itemType>other</itemType>
      <id>0002</id>
    </mediaCollection>
    <mediaCollection>
      <itemType>other</itemType>
      <id>0003</id>
    </mediaCollection>
    ....
```

(there is an extra layer of "mediaCollection" in my result that I need to get rid of)

I'm not sure how to accomplish this on the C# side of things since the idea of collection items just "floating" like this inside a class doesn't make sense (at least not to me).

I'm guessing maybe there is some namespace tweaking or some attributes I can apply in the interface contract that might accomplish this, but since I'm not sure how to phrase what I'm looking for, I'm having a hard time finding it.